# Custom salt with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have my own enctypter, using devise's encyptable module.However i cant set my own salt. Is there any way to force use own salt?

I've tried to create salt using

```
def password_salt
'test'
end
```

But that didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From version 2.1 if you want to use a custom encryptor you need to use another gem: [Devise Encryptable](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise-encryptable). Taken from the documentation you need:

Add it to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "devise-encryptable"
```

Add it to your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :encryptable
end
```

Add a migration on user model:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :password_salt, :string
  end
end
```

To modify the password you only need to change the value on database or use the method `User.password_salt(new_salt)`. Remember that you may need update the passwords to use the new salt.

Comment: I'm using this gem, and have following in my model
`:encryptable, :encryptor => :sha1` But i need to modify password_salt manually